# Where to find a dataset with literal data already annotated with dbpedia property concepts (having their range in float or int)?

Tags: dataset, ontology, dbpedia

I'm working on a project that tries to map `DBpedia` concepts to table data columns. Specifically I wanted to map literal(numerical values; float, int..). Therefore I need adequate number of data to build a background knowledge base. I extract some data from `T2D-golden-dataset` as the given format at the end of this description. Actually I should use them as a bench mark for testing and it only contains less than 20 columns from overall tables. Could anyone help me to find such a literal valued and `dbpedia` annotated dataset ?

Literal valued dbpedia ranges;

```
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float"
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger"
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
```

Some properties having these ranges;

```
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/speaker",
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/ranking",
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/humanDevelopmentIndex",
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/numberOfPlatformLevels",
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/enginePower",
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/graySubject",
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/shareOfAudience",
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/percentageLiteracyWomen",.........
```

Sample examples I need to found or somehow generate is an array corresponding to concepts given above. For an example;

```
 "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/enginePower" : ["220", "125", "1300",....],
 "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/humanDevelopmentIndex" : ["0.34", "0.78", "0.98", ...]
```

I don't need that exact format. It would be great If I can find enough number of data tables given as `T2D golden dataset` for `dbpedia`.

Comment: Your wish and goals are unclear. More detail *may* help. Also, the [dbpedia-discussion mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/dbpedia/mailman/dbpedia-discussion/) may be a better place to ask for this assistance.

Comment: @TallTed, Could you please go again through the question and help me?

Comment: I'm still puzzled. And not only because you're wrapping URI strings with double-quotes (which means they'll generally be treated as literal strings) instead of angle-brackets (which preserves their URI typing). It sounds like you *might* be trying to somehow transform DBpedia data from RDF-graph data to SQL-tabular data? I suggest you give us a big-pictured idea of what you're trying to accomplish overall, as well as more detail of how you've tried to achieve *this step* in that process (e.g., what queries have you run? what's wrong with the results you've gotten?).

Comment: I did not try querying dbpedia but I download `t2d gold-data-set` and it has tables with columns having some of the list of my specific property types. I could simply get the format I have given in the end of the prob. description. I downloaded a dbpedia sample from [here](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.9/en/) named as `mappingbased_properties_cleaned_en.nt`. Using `rdf-lib` I can query it. Is there a way to query `dbpedia public api` to query by giving property type and get some or all the instance values for that as given at the end of the description.

Comment: Please note that DBpedia 3.9 is not current (and is not in the public endpoint); the version labeling changed at that point. <http://downloads.dbpedia.org/current/> is a symlink to <http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2016-10/>, which is found in the public endpoint. I also note that [T2D Gold Standard for Matching Web Tables to DBpedia](http://webdatacommons.org/webtables/goldstandard.html) has been updated to [T2Dv2](http://webdatacommons.org/webtables/goldstandardV2.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fvalue%0D%0AWHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fsubject%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FpopulationTotal%3E%20%3Fvalue%20%7D%20%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) starts you down the road, as it gets you [100 typed literal values](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fvalue%0D%0AWHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fsubject%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FpopulationTotal%3E%20%3Fvalue%20%7D%20%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) for `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/populationTotal>`, which are all typed as `<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger>` --

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?value
WHERE 
  { ?subject dbo:populationTotal ?value } 
LIMIT 100
```

[This rather more complex (and expensive) query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20xsd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%23%20DISTINCT%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fvalue%20%3Fvalue_type%20%3Fvalue_str%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fvalue_type%20%28%20GROUP_CONCAT%20%28%20DISTINCT%20%3Fvalue_str%20%3B%20separator%3D%22%2C%20%22%20%29%20AS%20%3Fvalues%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fsubject%20%20%3Fpredicate%20%20%3Fvalue%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%20%3Fpredicate%20%29%20%7B%20%28%20dbo%3AnumberOfPlatformLevels%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%20dbo%3AshareOfAudience%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%20dbo%3ApopulationTotal%20%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%23%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20DATATYPE%20%28%20%3Fvalue%20%29%20%3D%20xsd%3AnonNegativeInteger%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%20%28%20DATATYPE%20%28%20%3Fvalue%20%29%20AS%20%3Fvalue_type%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%20%28%20%20%20%20%20%20STR%20%28%20%3Fvalue%20%29%20AS%20%3Fvalue_str%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fvalue_type%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fvalue_type%0D%0ALIMIT%201000&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) gets you [something like the end result I think you want](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20%20xsd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%23%20DISTINCT%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fvalue%20%3Fvalue_type%20%3Fvalue_str%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fvalue_type%20%28%20GROUP_CONCAT%20%28%20DISTINCT%20%3Fvalue_str%20%3B%20separator%3D%22%2C%20%22%20%29%20AS%20%3Fvalues%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fsubject%20%20%3Fpredicate%20%20%3Fvalue%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%20%3Fpredicate%20%29%20%7B%20%28%20dbo%3AnumberOfPlatformLevels%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%20dbo%3AshareOfAudience%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%20dbo%3ApopulationTotal%20%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%23%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20DATATYPE%20%28%20%3Fvalue%20%29%20%3D%20xsd%3AnonNegativeInteger%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%20%28%20DATATYPE%20%28%20%3Fvalue%20%29%20AS%20%3Fvalue_type%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%20%28%20%20%20%20%20%20STR%20%28%20%3Fvalue%20%29%20AS%20%3Fvalue_str%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fvalue_type%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fvalue_type%0D%0ALIMIT%201000&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) -- but you will need to run it a number of times, for a few predicates at a time, to get everything you're asking for from the public endpoint.  If needed, you could [spin up your own DBpedia mirror instance in the AWS cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07BQKYGYQ), and adjust Virtuoso's timeouts and other limits, in order to build and run one query that would deliver one giant result set.

```
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT # DISTINCT ?predicate ?value ?value_type ?value_str
                  ?predicate ?value_type ( GROUP_CONCAT ( DISTINCT ?value_str ; separator=", " ) AS ?values )
WHERE 
  { ?subject  ?predicate  ?value 
    VALUES ( ?predicate ) { ( dbo:numberOfPlatformLevels )
                            ( dbo:shareOfAudience )
                            ( dbo:populationTotal ) 
                          }
      BIND ( DATATYPE ( ?value ) AS ?value_type )
      BIND (      STR ( ?value ) AS ?value_str )
  } 
GROUP BY ?predicate ?value_type
ORDER BY ?predicate ?value_type
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Thankss a lot! @TallTed, This is what I actually wanted. Thanks for the guidance also. I had changed my mind to create these data using google table search. Now I can go along the original way.